# Is it possible to have two different resolutions in two different windows?

Tags: display-resolution

Is it possible to have two different resolutions on different windows?  Not two different monitors or even desktops but I would like to run everything at 1080 or 2K and then only have mpv in 4K?  The nvidia settings have application specific  settings but that dosnt seem to deal with resolution.  I have been looking and reading everything I can find but it’s all about two monitor setups and that seems pretty straight forward but well any help or just point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Is this even possible?

Setup
Ubuntu 18.04 lts 
Nvidia 2060 super
Amd 3950x

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not possible. You can only have one resolution per monitor.
But putting each window on a different monitor with a different resultion is possible.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply I was fairly certain it wasn’t possible but didn’t want to not ask.  Yeah that’s how I am doing it not using my second monitor for media and my main monitor for everything else.  But thanks for the answer.